# Timestamp to date conversion

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following input /output but the last output is not the expected. I would the timestamp to give the current date but it seems that the conversion change the decimal of the time in the datetime. Any help would be appreciated.

code:

```
  used_list['expiration_timestamp'] = (used_list['expiration_timestamp']/1000)
```

input:

```
0      1.584605e+09
1      1.593158e+09
2      1.601021e+09
3      1.601021e+09
4      1.584518e+09
           ...     
165    1.584691e+09
166    1.584691e+09
167    1.601021e+09
168    1.584605e+09
169    1.601021e+09
```

code2:

```
used_list['expiration_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(used_list['expiration_timestamp'])
```

output:

```
0     1970-01-01 00:00:01.584604800
1     1970-01-01 00:00:01.593158400
2     1970-01-01 00:00:01.601020800
3     1970-01-01 00:00:01.601020800
4     1970-01-01 00:00:01.584518400
                   ...             
165   1970-01-01 00:00:01.584691200
166   1970-01-01 00:00:01.584691200
167   1970-01-01 00:00:01.601020800
168   1970-01-01 00:00:01.584604800
169   1970-01-01 00:00:01.601020800
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT 1st row:

```
 0  03/19/2020
```

Comment: what's your expect output?

Comment: @gamesun  I have edited, please look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas by default expects nanoseconds when using numbers to dates (I think)

try

```
pd.to_datetime(used_list['expiration_timestamp'],unit="s")
```

to tell pandas its actually seconds

Comment: I would like to have the Y-m-d, not only the second. please look at my edit

Comment: did you try this ... this includes Y-m-d ... if you only want the date and not the time do 

`my_new_datetime_column.dt.date`

Comment: Thanks, I miss understood the way it should be used but it actually worked